# Finding the count of Interactions between Members located in the Dataset

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a pass traffic data which shows the pass traffic between Members, [here's the sample dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5cu0xyfef9w5up7/J_H1S1T5.csv)

It shows the Interactions between Members in consecutive rows. I want to count that interactions, and obtain a new dataset which shows how many interactions occured between Members for Each Member, the direction doesn't matters

For example:

```
between 26 and 11 = X
between 26 and 27 = Y
```

I just can't figure it out which function I can use and how can I write a code for this calculation. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `rollaply` function from the `zoo` package to find all interactions. The frequency of these interactions could be calculated using `table`. (I assume your object is called `dat`.)

```
library(zoo)
table(as.data.frame(rollapply(dat[[1]], 2, sort)))
```

The result:

```
    V2
V1    4  8 10 11 13 17 19 25 26 27 53
  4   2 13 17  1  2  5  6  3  1  9  4
  8   0  2 14 11 10  4  5  0 13 13 11
  10  0  0  3  9  7  2  4  2  8 11  8
  11  0  0  0  1  6  5  4  4  5  4 25
  13  0  0  0  0  0  1  3  5  7  9  8
  17  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  5  5
  19  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  5  4
  25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  5  8  5
  26  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  5  3
  27  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
  53  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

The lower triangular part of the matrix contains zeros only since the direction does not matter.

If you are not interested in interactions between the same values, use the following command:

```
table(as.data.frame(rollapply(rle(dat[[1]])$values, 2, sort)))

    V2
V1    8 10 11 13 17 19 25 26 27 53
  4  13 17  1  2  5  6  3  1  9  4
  8   0 14 11 10  4  5  0 13 13 11
  10  0  0  9  7  2  4  2  8 11  8
  11  0  0  0  6  5  4  4  5  4 25
  13  0  0  0  0  1  3  5  7  9  8
  17  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  5  5
  19  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  5  4
  25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  5  8  5
  26  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  5  3
  27  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: There's a rather interesting non-R question that followed this calculation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860390/visualizing-the-pass-traffic-data-with-chord-diagram#comment19088652_13860390

Comment: @ Sven, How can I make the lower triangular contain the interactions ?

Comment: @forochelian `table(as.data.frame(rollapply(rle(dat[[1]])$values, 2, sort))[c(2,1)])` or use the function `t` with the existing matrix

Comment: @ Sven, oh I'm sorry, I mean, both lower and upper triangular.

Comment: @forochelian Should both triangulars be identical?

Comment: @Sven Yeah, since I will use `levelplot()` to display the output, I want to show symmetrical values. When I try to use your code, the lower or upper triangular part remains empty in the plot, I just want to show that part too.

Comment: @forochelian You could create a symmetric matrix, `tab`, with the following commands: `tab <- table(as.data.frame(rollapply(dat[[1]], 2, sort))); tab[lower.tri(tab)] <- t(tab)[lower.tri(tab)]`
`