# Visualizing the pass traffic data with Chord Diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, chord-diagram

I have a pass traffic data between players, [here's the data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cqxj4wx2czi9j4e/J_H2S1T6_PassTraffic.csv), first column and first row indicate the Player Numbers.

I want to visualize this data like [Uber Rides](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/). I think it was built with [Chord Diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/4062006) from Bostock's.

Since I almost have no experience in JavaScript, I just don't know where to begin.

How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i got with your data

[image]
I just replaced the matrix array with your array

[2,3,1,0,0,2,0,6,5,2,5,0,3],
[0,7,2,0,4,7,0,1,2,0,3,0,2],
[0,0,4,1,5,3,3,0,1,1,5,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,4,0,5,4,2,0,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,2,0,1,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,1,1,9,1,6],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,0,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,0,8],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2]

I  am not claiming this to be correct but just giving you a idea how simply you can achieve this with the work people already did.

Comment: Player 3 is not on the 1st row, since it already placed at the first column. Like this, Player 91 is not on the 1st Column

Comment: @ Fud, and How can I replace the "0k" labels with the Jersey Number, which is placed on the first column and row ?

Comment: do you see the line ticks.append('text', function(d){ });
Now d.target.index can give you the corresponding row and isntead of d.label you can use the index to look up the user a that row and return its value

Comment: i would have made a gist but github seems to be giving 404 when saving a gist at this very moment.

Comment: Thanks FUD, It was a great help.

Comment: @ FUD, I still couldn't figure it out how to put Jersey Numbers into the diagram. Can you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: Sorry i may not have been very clear really.. http://jsfiddle.net/JJqLK
But please check if the data makes sense as according to me rows and column headers should be same